# $f=f'+f''$ implies $f\equiv 0.$

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

I have trouble understanding why is $f''(d)<0$ in case 1 and $f''(d)>0$ in case 2. I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: @DMcMor That's not true. Consider $f(x) = 1-x^4$ on $[-1,1].$

Answer (score 2):

You are on to something. That's a pretty bad proof. I would argue this way: At $d$ we have $f(d)>0,f'(d)=0.$ From the given equation it follows that $f''(d)=f(d) > 0.$ But if $f''(d) > 0,$ then

$$\frac{f'(d+h)-f'(d)}{h} = \frac{f'(d+h)}{h} > 0$$

for small positive $h.$ This implies $f'>0$ on some interval $(d,d+h_0).$ That in turn implies $f$ is strictly increasing on $[d,d+h_0).$ Thus $f>f(d)$ in $(d,d+h_0).$ That contradicts the fact that $f(d)$ was the maximum value of $f$ on $[0,1].$

Comment: It seems unnecessary to completely discard a proof where replacing one instance each of $<$ and $>$ with $\le$ and $\ge$ respectively would fix it.

Comment: It's a bad error for a book iin my opinion. And why is the result OK with $\le?$ I don't know what the OP knows, so I gave a proof of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is almost fine. Replace in Case 1 the clause

"Then $f(d)>0$ and $f'(d)=0$ and $f''(d)<0$"

by

"Then $f(d)>0$,  $f'(d)=0$, and $f''(d)\leq0$, or $f$ would not be locally maximal at $d$."

Similarly in Case 2.

Answer (score 0):

If $f(d)$ is a local maximum, you know that the derivative $f'(d) = 0$, and the derivative shortly before $d$ is positive and shortly after $d$, negative. This can only happen if the derivative of the derivative, $f''(d)$ is non-positive. And it can't be 0, because then $f(d)=f'(d)+f''(d)$ would be 0 as well. So it must be negative.

A similar reasoning holds for the second case.

Comment: No, $f''(d)=0$ is possible at a local max, even a strict global max as in my comment above.

Comment: @zhw. classic mistake, thanks for pointing it out. It seems you need to combine it with the $f = f' + f''$ property.